# Get current type of internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the technology of radio access (internet connection), so detect if the device is connected to Wifi or WWAN connection (and in this case, which type of WWAN : GPRS, EGDE, 3G, 3G+, 3G++, or 4G).

Does **CTTelephonyNetworkInfo** works for iPhone and iPad on iOS7.1 ?

I've tried to detect a Wifi connection on an iPad but I print a null result.
This is my code :

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
NSLog(@"Current Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
```

Someone can told me why ? I'm not sure to understand everything about this...

Thanks for your help

(Source : http://www.objc.io/issue-5/iOS7-hidden-gems-and-workarounds.html, section "Know your Radio")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `currentRadioAccessTechnology` will return the radio access technology (not whether it's Wifi or WWAN). An example of return value is `CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE`.

To get informed about whether your app is connect to Wifi or WWAN, you should use [Reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177066/how-to-use-ios-reachability).

There are [several implementations available](http://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20reachability).

Comment: And if I want to know if this WWAN connection is GPRS, EDGE, 3G, 3G or something else ? I guess these implementations allows me to make a distinction between Wifi and WWAN connection, no ?

Comment: You'd need to use both of them: Reachability to know if it's a WWAN connection, then `- [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo currentRadioAccessTechnology]` to know what kind of WWAN it is.

Comment: Seems to be logic... Thanks for your help !

Comment: While this detects which WWAN connection is supported, it won't tell you if it's actually using it.  So say I have an iPhone capable of LTE, but if I'm in an area with 3G only, it'll still report LTE.